# Best way to update features on rails apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git

I have deployed my rails apps in production ( digital ocean ) I store all my code in github and clone it on live server. The question is how to update the latest apps?

For example:
I customized my rails apps on my computer ( local ) and I push all the code the repo ( github / bitbucket ) . How do I update the live server based on the repo I have made changed? Did I need to delete all the rails folder in server and clone it again?
Thanks guys

Comment: err.. im not familiar with the digital ocean setup but are you not able to access git in the folder and push the code again?

Comment: @ValAsensio ya. I'm using SSH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, you can use remote server automation and deployment tool written in Ruby.

There are several tool for automation and deployment but most popular is capistrano.

https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano

Installing and configuire capistrano is easy.

Here is a blog post for how you use capistrano.

This is a two part blog on how to use it:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorial_series/how-to-use-capistrano-to-automate-deployments